# How to create and then show a jQuery Validate error message for 3 seconds

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I've looked around and seem a little confused as to what I need to do.
I'm using HTML5 validation attributes to declare the rules for the jQuery Validate plugin as well.

Here is my input

```
<input id="jumbotronSearch" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Location" required maxlength="50" minlength="4"/>
```

In my js file I have something that looks like this, but I'm not sure if I need to create a new rule or just somehow trigger a validation-error-message for 3 seconds?? Then after the 3 seconds I guess I need the mesage to disapear and the validation to be reset??

```js
var form = $('#form');
form.validate();

if (form.valid()) {
  // do something here to check a value
  if (somecheckfails) {
    // add a new rule to jquery validate
    // then trigger the rule to display the error message for 3 seconds only, then disapear
    // what is needed here? a new new rule or just something to trigger a validation-error-message?
  }
}
```

Comment: *"I'm using html5 validation with jquery validate as well"* ~ this is impossible as the jQuery Validate plugin dynamically disables all HTML5 validation.  Unless you simply meant that you're using HTML5 attributes to declare the validation rules for the plugin.

Comment: It's still unclear what you're trying to do.  You simply want the validation messages to disappear after 3 second and reset the form?  If so, you would not create new rules for this as the rules simply define the data requirements.  You would use the various `.validate()` options to control presentation.

Comment: yes if you look at my input I'm using minlength and maxlength and required. And the jquery validate just checks these attributes.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is this. I'm running form.validate, if the validation passes I go check something with google maps. If I get the result back that I want I move on, BUT if the google map service doesn't give me what I want I then want to display a error message where the jquery validate error message gets displayed. Additionally I only want to show it for 3 seconds.

Comment: As agreed, with this plugin, you're not really doing any HTML5 validation, so I removed this tag.

Comment: Since the plugin controls the visibility of the message, what you ask may be impossible without modification of the core.  It would be helpful to see more relevant code to get a sense of what you just described.  Where is the jQuery Validate method that checks Google Maps?

Comment: ok, that's understandable. I just thought that I could somehow use the existing functionality of the jquery validate error message to show my error message, instead of creating some type of custom element just to show a error message to the user in the same place the jquery validate error message gets displayed. Key here is to show it in the same place as the jquery validation error message

Comment: There are a bunch of ways to work around the defaults.  I'm just telling you that I can't think of anything with what little code you've shown.

Comment: I'm not posting this jsFiddle as an answer because we still cannot see enough code to know how to help you.  However, here is a proof-of-concept:  http://jsfiddle.net/rgqLbzdd/ ~ Now you simply need to move that trigger into your event so it's automatic.

Answer (score -2):

I think I will just bypass jquery validate and display my own error message. Here is what I will do.

Add a label element just like a jquery validation error message and in my js code
just call

```js
$('#jumbotronSearch).show().fadeout(3000);
```

```html
<input id="jumbotronSearch" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Location" required maxlength="50" minlength="4" />
<label id="location-error" for="jumbotronSearch" style="display: none;">The location was not found.</label>
```

Comment: The Code Snippets feature is only for  a complete code demo that you can actually run within this window.